# absolute positioning inside to relative parent overflows div when padding set

Tags: html, css

Thats my codepen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/JoKmQr

run on IE 11.

Why does the right red div Overflow into the Screen when I set the padding of 5% to the itemContainer?

```
<div style="background:lightblue;">Absolute position inside container</div>
<div id="itemContainer"> 
  <div class="item i1">1</div>
  <div class="item i2">2</div>
  <div class="item i3">3</div>
</div>


* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html { 
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%; 
}

.item{
  position:absolute;
}

#itemContainer{
  background:orange;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  padding:5%;
}

.item.i1 {
   width: 50%; 
   height:50%;
   background:lightgreen;
}

.item.i2 {
   width: 50%; 
   height:50%;
   top:50%;
   background:lightgray;;
}

.item.i3 {
   width: 50%; 
   height:100%;  
   left: 50%;
   background:red;   
}
```

**UPDATE**

My Goal is put 3 items on the Screen with a "2-column"-layout and the item of the 2nd "column" should simulate a "Rowspan" by giving it 100% height while item 1 and 2 have 50% height.

Comment: Are you trying to hide it?

Comment: hide what? I have updated my init question with more Information what I try to achieve! As I have border-box set I thought the padding should not be computed to the size but it is only item3 which is overflowing?

Comment: Yeah got it i thought you were trying to hide the overflowing red div

Comment: That's the nature of absolutely positioned elements; they tend to ignore the flow of everything...which is why you're having your right column spill over outside the container. I would suggest rewriting the CSS to not use `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because padding is counted as part of the height - If you were to put an 'inner' div to your `#itemContainer` and set the padding on the outer div, you'd be able to fix it. See my fork here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJMMoZ

Comment: Why is padding counted as part of the height? I thought padding is not counted at all with boder-box?

Comment: With border-box, a div with a 50% width and 10% padding remains at a 50% width, so technically, the padding becomes part of the total height.

Comment: This solution is right. @Pascal: in your example, The padding is not counted for the `width:50%;` of the childs element. Thats the problem here. The child elements still are 50% of the browser width, because the parent element is 100% of the browsers width...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the padding (when using box-sizing: border-box;).

The #itemContainer has position:relative.

The children divs (.item)  have position:absolute.

To absolute position the children (.item), the browser needs to know relative to where (top,left,right and bottom).

In your example simply add these "positioning" properties to your absolute positioned divs:

```
.item{
  position:absolute;
}    


.item.i1 {
       width: 50%; 
       height:50%;
       background:lightgreen;
      top:0;
      left:0;
    }

    .item.i2 {
       width: 50%; 
       height:50%;
       top:50%;
       background:lightgray;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
    }

    .item.i3 {
       width: 50%; 
       height:100%;  
       left: 50%;
       background:red;  
      top:0;
      right:0;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgWVjY

Answer (score 0):

Padding is counted as addition to width/height of the content elements without noticing its padding.

If you got 5% padding, you need to set the content to 90% width and height, because you already have 10% padding (5% top and 5% bottom respectively 5% left and 5% right.

For your 50% content blocks, you need to change it to 45%.
100% gets 90%.

This way it should fit.

Comment: But he's using `box-sizing: border-box;` So padding is not an addition.

Comment: but still the 50% width of the content elements are 50% of the outers element width, that is 100% width. so teh elements get 50% width of the whole browser window.

Comment: Yes but a block element with `box-sizing: border-box;`, `width: 50%` and `padding: 5%` still has a 50% width.

Comment: thats because in your example the inner element with 50% width has the padding, not the outer element. percentages are calculated from the outer element's width/height _without_ noticing its padding.

Comment: No, the outer element has the padding - not the inner element.

Comment: i was talking about your example 3 lines above, not about your codepen example. your codepen works, because by adding the outer div the inner divs percentages relate to the new div you created, which has no padding.

Comment: It was a generic example about box-sizing, there is no outer or inner element in that example.

Comment: `outer` = div with padding, `inner` = div with 50% width/height. your example worked because you had padding and 50% in the same div, so it gets calculated correctly.

Comment: you guys are confusing me.

Comment: Apologies @Pascal, see my answer - it fixes your issue.

Comment: i dont know whats the problem here.. percentage width of inner element gets calculated from width of outer element. your outer element had 100% width, so inner element gets 50% width. problem was, you were thinking that 50% width would be aware of the padding of the outer element, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rewriting your code so it doesn't use absolutely positioned elements, especially for things like columns, or else you're going to keep running into issues like this. And having to reduce your width from 100% because of padding shouldn't be a requirement, especially when border-box would have prevented that need, but even then I still suggest something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="leftCol">

        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>    

    </div><!--

 --><div class="rightCol">

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .container {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        height: 500px;
        padding: 25px;
        background: #DDD;}

    .leftCol,
    .rightCol {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;}

    .leftCol {
        background: #BBB;}

    .rightCol {
        background: #CCC;}

    .box1 {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background: gray;}

    .box2 {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background: #555;}
```